# Java Script Классы. Использование this из методов.

Tags: javascript

Есть класс Ball.

```
function Ball(x, y, id)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.id = id;

    Ball.prototype.draw = function()
    {
        ctx.drawImage(sprite1, 0, 0);
    }    
}
```

Каким образом можно использовать "this.x" и "this.y" вместо нулей в функции drawImage()?

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
Ball = function ( x, y, id){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.id = id;
}

Ball.prototype.draw = function (){
  ctx.drawImage( sprite1, this.x, this.y );
}
```

Обратите внимание на `ctx и sprite1`, имхо - если уж это какие-то глобальные объекты, то:

1. Или передавать их в конструктор и хранить в объекте
2. Или сделать параметрами функции